# Using a fully charged Galaxy Note

Tags: battery, samsung-galaxy-note, battery-life

Is it safe to use a Galaxy Note that is fully charged and at the same time it is plugged in to the wall socket? I'm worried that the battery might be charging and discharging at the same time and it will tremendously produce severe stress in the battery. Thus it will shorten the lifespan of the battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup, It is perfectly fine. I do it regularly while playing games.